# Does Wildfly 18 Supports Seam 2.3 Applications?

Tags: jsf, wildfly, seam

I want to migrate an application from Wildfly 8 to the latest Wildfly 18. The web application uses the following frameworks: hibernate 3, seam 2.2, JSF 1.2, and Richfaces 3.3.3. Since hibernate 3 isn't supported anymore in Wildfly, we need to migrate to hibernate 4 which isn't compatible with Seam 2.2. Thus, we have to migrate to Seam 2.3 and this leads to migrating to JSF 2.3 (Wildfly modules) and to  Richfaces 4.

My project is an ear that contains inside it a war folder.
For JSF, I am using the supported module by Wildfly both com.sun.faces.impl and javax.faces.api. I also added jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar as a jar under web-inf/lib.

For hibernate, I included the following jars in my ear: hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, and hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar.

For seam, I included the seam jars: jboss-seam.jar, jboss-seam-debug.jar, ...

For Richfaces, I included the following libraries under the war folder:  richfaces-a4j-4.5.17.Final.jar, richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar, and richfaces-rich-4.5.17.Final.jar. I also included their dependencies.

I am still getting this error which I am not able to debug: Unsupported Operation Exception.

Did anyone encountered this issue ? And do you know if Seam 2.3 is still supported by the latest Wildfly especially that on Seam documentation, they gave the project examples on Jboss As 7?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration you are trying to achieve will result in a non-supported environment as well.

1. From http://seamframework.org/

> **Seam Moving Forward**
>
> As many of you may be aware, there have been a number of changes
> within Seam over the past year. Here is a quick highlight of the
> changes and how they may affect you and your application.
>
> **Seam 2**
> Seam 2.2 targets JBoss AS 5 and 6 as well as JBoss Enterprise
> Application Platform 5 - Java EE 5 based architecture Seam 2.3 targets
> Java EE 6 capabilities such as JSF2 and JPA2 on the JBoss Enterprise
> Application Platform 6 - Seam 2.3 also supports RichFaces 4 which is
> also available for commercial support via Web Framework Kit. If you
> are looking for the long-term support with a service level agreement
> of Seam 2.2 and/or Seam 2.3 then please contact us at
> http://www.redhat.com/contact/sales.html Seam 2.3 is part of Web
> Framework Kit, included as part of the JBoss Enterprise Application
> Platform subscription .
>
> Seam 2.3 was released in September 2012. This is an update to the Seam
> 2 code base to make it compatible with Jave EE 6. It runs well on
> JBoss AS 7.
>
> **Seam 3**
> Active development of Seam 3 has been halted by Red Hat. Many projects
> have moved over to Apache DeltaSpike , and others have been absorbed
> into different projects. Please see the below table for information
> about where the functionality from each module has gone and how you
> can participate.

So no, it does not support WildFly 18 (Java EE 8)

2. Richfaces is 'dead' (sunset) for 4 years now. https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesEnd-Of-LifeQuestionsAnswers
3. JSF 2.x has facelets built-in, so no need to include them. (Causes problems even)
4. Wildfly 18 has JPA2 built-in so no need to include hibernate manually (Might cause problems even)
5. Also read https://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.3.0.Final/reference/en-US/html/migration23.html

Switching to using

- PrimeFaces (fully html 5, css3 etc compliant)
- JPA2
- CDI (with Deltaspike)
- OmniFaces
- OptimusFaces

is a way better thing to do (Although JSF is 'old' compared to e.t.c. Angular it is still modern when combined with the above technologies and more stable).